# How do I write this multiple index tensor equation using Ricci calculus where the 4-gradient is acting on each tensor?

Tags: tensors, index-notation

In the context of special relativity I have this to show that this equation is correct: $$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu}=j^\nu$$

To do that I'm trying to take this equation:
$$F^{\mu \nu}=\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}-\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}$$
and take the 4-gradient of it:
$$\partial_\mu F^{\mu \nu}=\partial_\mu\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}-\partial_\mu\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}$$
I'm not sure what to do at this point, I think my main problem is that I see these written here and I'm not sure I know what it means. From what I understand $$\partial_\mu=\bigg({\partial\over \partial t},-\vec\nabla\bigg),$$
but I don't know what $\partial^{\mu}$ or $\partial^{\nu}$ are equal to. What happens to $A^{\nu}$ and $A^{\mu}$ when they are acted on by $\partial^{\mu}$ and $\partial^\nu$, respectively? Is this even the right approach to prove that $\partial_\mu F^{\mu\nu}=j^\nu$?

Answer (score 1):

You can lower and raise indices with the metric, which in the case of special relativity is

$$
\eta^{\mu \nu} = \pmatrix{1 &  0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & -1} \tag{1}
$$

As an example

$$
\partial^\mu = \eta^{\mu \nu}\partial_\nu \tag{2}
$$

It is then easy to calculate

\begin{eqnarray}
\require{cancel}
\partial^0 &=& \eta^{0\nu}\partial_\nu = \cancelto{1}{\eta^{00}}\partial_0 = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \\
\partial^i &=& \eta^{i\nu}\partial_\nu = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} ~~~\mbox{for}~~ i = 1,2,3\tag{3}
\end{eqnarray}

Same applies for the field $F^{\mu\nu}$,

$$
F^{\mu\nu} = \eta^{\nu\beta}F^{\mu}_{\;\beta} = \eta^{\mu\alpha} \eta^{\nu\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}
$$